# Integrate Microsoft Bot to exist WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, asp.net-core-webapi, app-startup

I have a ASP.NET Core project with only *Controllers* (WebAPI).
I realized that Microsoft Bot is only a middleware for an ASP.NET server, it is even defined in the WebHost startup methods.

Can I take an existing project and add to it the middleware of the bot?
Will it retain the ability to access endpoints directly using REST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, this is 100% possible and was one of the goals of the integration layer from day one.

The one thing you want to make sure is that you place your `.UseBotFramework()` call before the `.UseMvc()` call so that it takes priority on processing the request and so that the default MVC routes don't take over and swallow the request.

I would suggest the following order for a basic web app that has static files, a bot and MVC controllers:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles()
       .UseStaticFiles()
       .UseBotFramework()
       .UseMvc();    
}
```